# How to programmatically use Spring's JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-jdbc

We use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` which is configured through Spring config as illustrated below.  Is there a way to do this without injecting the data source?  I'd like to just create the `JdbcTemplate` instance programmatically and "initalize" the datasource using `TheOracleDS`.

Our current config:

*Java class*

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Resource(name = "myDataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
     this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

*Spring config*

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="java:/TheOracleDS"/>
```

*Oracle datasource config*

```
<xa-datasource>
      <jndi-name>TheOracleDS</jndi-name>
      ...
</xa-datasource>
```

---

**Update**: Reason I'm asking this is I'm not a total believer in dependency injection / having Spring manage beans..

Comment: The real question is: why is injection not desirable here?  What is doing it the way you're proposing buying you?

Comment: I've gone the non-injection route before with Spring JDBC, but only for utility classes where I just want to run a main method to check something in the database.  In that case writing an XML and looking it up does seem a bit overkill.  However, once JNDI is in the mix, it seems like there really isn't a case to avoid using injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a raw JNDI lookup:

```
public void setDataSourceName(String name) {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate((DataSource) ctx.lookup(name));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's some sample code from a project I've written:

```
SimpleJdbcTemplate db;
DataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource(System.getProperty(
         "lingcog.db.connectstring"),
      System.getProperty("lingcog.db.username"),
      System.getProperty("lingcog.db.password"), false);

db = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

Maybe my code would be simpler if I used injection, but this is a good example of how to do this without using injection.

You can use an `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup` object to find the data source you want by JDNI name.

```
DataSource dataSource = new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("java:/TheOracleDS")
SimpleJdbcTemplate db=new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why you want to do that but... you could lookup the JDNI datasource with Spring's `JndiDataSourceLookup`:

```
JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
lookup.setResourceRef(true); // if the lookup occurs in a J2EE container
DataSource ds = lookup.getDataSource(jndiName);
```

Or just perform a "manual" lookup using Sun's classes:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/AcmeDB");
```

Then, just pass the datasource reference to the `JdbcTemplate` constructor or call `setDataSource(ds)`.

But, as I said, I have no idea why you don't want to use injection.